# How do I delete a pattern in a column using sed command line?

Tags: sed, command-line, command, delete

I have a table like this below;

```
"baseMean"  "log2FoldChange"    "lfcSE" "stat"  "pvalue"    "padj"
"ENSG00000000003.14"    11.3434183210348    0.753849141787545   0.682104979689654   1.10518052826785    0.269081372382168   0.999928163137131
"ENSG00000000419.12"    793.733816508413    -0.256066185652526  0.133681398896401   -1.91549600592503   0.0554292780227467  0.863889514659372
"ENSG00000000457.13"    948.240987147508    -0.088027064401221  0.0869481579436567  -1.01240861776811   0.3113427195966
```

And I want to delete the quotation marks and `.X` pattern in 1st column. I mean like this:

```
"baseMean"  "log2FoldChange"    "lfcSE" "stat"  "pvalue"    "padj"
ENSG00000000003 11.3434183210348    0.753849141787545   0.682104979689654   1.10518052826785    0.269081372382168   0.999928163137131
ENSG00000000419 793.733816508413    -0.256066185652526  0.133681398896401   -1.91549600592503   0.0554292780227467  0.863889514659372
ENSG00000000457 948.240987147508    -0.088027064401221  0.0869481579436567  -1.01240861776811   0.3113427195966
```

In this case, how can I write command line using sed or whatever?

Answer (score 0):

**Using `sed`:**

```
$ echo \"ENSG00000009694.13\" 3.25851232080741 0.670268379884225 | sed -E "s|\"(.+?)\.[0-9]*\"|\1|g"
ENSG00000009694 3.25851232080741 0.670268379884225
```

I guess what you are dealing with is a huge log file. In this case, you can use

```
$ sed -E "s|\"(.+?)\.[0-9]*\"|\1|g" your_file.txt
"baseMean"  "log2FoldChange"    "lfcSE" "stat"  "pvalue"    "padj"
ENSG00000000003    11.3434183210348    0.753849141787545   0.682104979689654   1.10518052826785    0.269081372382168   0.999928163137131
```

and `sed` will print the result. You can also add a `-i` in front of `-E`; `-i` stands for "in place mode" so sed will directly modify your file.

**Explanation:**

I am using the "find and replace" function of sed. The basic grammar is

```
sed -E "s|p1|p2|g"
```

and then sed will replace `p1` with `p2`. `-E` stand for "extended regex mode" so `p1` can be some complicated regex.

My `p1` here is (omit `(` and `)` for now)

```
\".+?\.[0-9]*\"
```

in which

- `\"` maches the quotation marks,
- `\.[0-9]*` maches patterns starting with a dot and have 0 to infinity numbers in the following and
- `.+?` maches any patterns in the middle.

Then `p2` is simply a `\1` which means the string between the first `(` and `)` pair in `p1`. And it is done!

Comment: Note that `.+?` is a PCRE non-greedy match.  Fro whatever reason, GNU `sed` seems to accept this illegal extended regular expression. You don't need the `?` after `.+` as you match a literal double quote later. There is also no real reason to change the default delimiters for the `s` command here, or to use extended regular expressions.

Comment: Yes, the `?` is only a habit of Python regex. I myself think this is a good habit because it reduces many mistakes. The reason for changing the default delimiter from `/` to `|` is because this is much easy to read. Without `-E`, the sed on my computer throughs out an error `sed: -e expression #1, char 22: invalid reference \1 on \`s' command's RHS`. So I think this is another good habit to stick to `-E`.

Comment: You get that error without `-E` because a capture group is written `\(...\)` without `-E`. Note too that `-E` is non-standard.

Comment: Yes, without `-E` there will be a lot of \, and very hard to read as a result. So it is better to always use `-E`.

Comment: My choices have their reason and they are the best based on my experience.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR>1{gsub(/\"/,"",$0);gsub(/\.[0-9]*/,"",$1)}1' filename
```

output

```
"baseMean"  "log2FoldChange"    "lfcSE" "stat"  "pvalue"    "padj"
ENSG00000000003 11.3434183210348 0.753849141787545 0.682104979689654 1.10518052826785 0.269081372382168 0.999928163137131
ENSG00000000419 793.733816508413 -0.256066185652526 0.133681398896401 -1.91549600592503 0.0554292780227467 0.863889514659372
ENSG00000000457 948.240987147508 -0.088027064401221 0.0869481579436567 -1.01240861776811 0.3113427195966
```

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
$ sed 's/^"\(ENS[[:alnum:]]*\)\..*"/"\1"/' file
"baseMean"  "log2FoldChange"    "lfcSE" "stat"  "pvalue"    "padj"
"ENSG00000000003"    11.3434183210348    0.753849141787545   0.682104979689654   1.10518052826785    0.269081372382168   0.999928163137131
"ENSG00000000419"    793.733816508413    -0.256066185652526  0.133681398896401   -1.91549600592503   0.0554292780227467  0.863889514659372
"ENSG00000000457"    948.240987147508    -0.088027064401221  0.0869481579436567  -1.01240861776811   0.3113427195966
```

The `sed` command above removes the version from the Ensembl stable IDs in the first column only.  It does this by means of matching `"ENS` at the start o the line, followed by any number of alphanumerical characters, a dot and some non-quote character.  The dot and the non-quote characters are discarded using a substitution.

To remove the double quotes as well, change the replacement text from `"\1"` to just `\1`.

If you are certain that there are always a version attached to the stable IDs, you may shorten this to the following expression, which just removes the first substring between a dot and a double quote:

```bsh
$ sed 's/\..*"/"/' file
"baseMean"  "log2FoldChange"    "lfcSE" "stat"  "pvalue"    "padj"
"ENSG00000000003"    11.3434183210348    0.753849141787545   0.682104979689654   1.10518052826785    0.269081372382168   0.999928163137131
"ENSG00000000419"    793.733816508413    -0.256066185652526  0.133681398896401   -1.91549600592503   0.0554292780227467  0.863889514659372
"ENSG00000000457"    948.240987147508    -0.088027064401221  0.0869481579436567  -1.01240861776811   0.3113427195966
```

Would you need to delete the quotes you could do that with the expression `2,$ s/"//g`, e.g.,

```bsh
sed -e 's/\..*"/"/' -e '2,$ s/"//g' file
```

Or, you could just pass everything through `tr -d '"'` to remove all quotes.

```bsh
sed 's/\..*"/"/' file | tr -d '"'
```

Comment: From the comments under the question (which have been deleted now), we know this is a new-to-Linux user who does not know what is `echo`. So I think my explanations are much fresh-bird-friendly. And as I have replied to you, every choice has its reason.

Comment: @Youran I'm not quite sure what you are commenting on now. My answer does not use `echo`.  It is clear that the user is a bioinformatician (possibly a student, maybe not) working with human genomic data. Such data is often large and stored on files on disk, which is why I assume that data is read from file.

Comment: My answer used `echo` to show the regex works. Then the author asked me what is `echo`. This was in the comments under the question (the comments are deleted now). We should be careful when asking newcomers questions. We should be user-friendly and explain everything patiently. I am very sure that he cannot understand your answer.

Comment: @Youran The user asked why you used `echo`, not what `echo` was.